# Is there a slideshow codec?

Tags: codec

Is there a video codec that deals well with slideshows?

A substantial fraction of videos are slideshows with an audio track.  An appropriate video codec would compress to little more than the audio track.  Yet it seems all the video codecs behave as though they assume the majority of video will contain motion.